# Google Data Studio - Full Outer Join Null Values & Pivot Table

Tags: join, pivot-table, looker-studio, outer-join

Google Data Studio recently introduced new join operations additional to the left outer join, the full outer join being one of them. A full outer join can obviously often lead to null values in the blended table.

If I have the following table  (`null` values represented by `-`) that results from a blend with a full outer join, with the join on

- Company Table 1 <-> Company Table 2
- Month Table 1 <-> Month Table 2

| Company Table 1 | Company Table 2 | Month Table 1 | Month Table 2 | Amount Table 1 | Amount Table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MUC | MUC | Jan 22 | Jan 22 | 1000 | 600 |
| MUC | MUC | Feb 22 | Feb 22 | 800 | 200 |
| MUC | MUC | Mar 22 | Mar 22 | 800 | 200 |
| MUC | - | Apr 22 | - | 900 | - |
| - | MUC | - | May 22 | - | 200 |

If I now create a pivot table from that blended data and I use `Company Table 1` as row dimension and `Month Table 1` as column dimension and `NARY_MAX(Amount Table 1,0) - NARY_MAX(Amount Table 2,0)` as the metric, I get get the following

|  | null | Jan 22 | Feb 22 | Mar 22 | Apr 22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MUC | - | 400 | 600 | 600 | 900 |
| null | -200 | - | - | - | - |

This is quite understandable, but my question is, if I could somehow tell Data Studio to use the dimensions `Company Table 2` and `Month Table 2` as dimensions if the ones from Table 1 are `null`.

The desired outcome would be

|  | Jan 22 | Feb 22 | Mar 22 | Apr 22 | May 22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MUC | 400 | 600 | 600 | 900 | -200 |

[Here](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e933171c-9cd8-4eba-a46e-2c789814a9bb) you can finde the above data in a publicly accessible and editable example

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`COALESCE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10522032) function ("*returns the first non-missing value found in a list of fields*") can be used to deal with the `NULL` values in both the `Company` and `Month` fields:

### 1) Company COALESCE

- ```
  COALESCE(Company (Table 1), Company (Table 2))
  ```
- ***Type***: Text

### 2) Month COALESCE

- ```
  COALESCE(Month (Table 1), Month (Table 2))
  ```
- ***Type***: Date > Year Month

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c3e58817-fb03-4eb8-8d69-50bbb08fb3db) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yyBgZftLi4j9EwXwbmwYT30bc3sOsOXZ6aNNY5DbaA0/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 4]